# "Бюллетень" во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "три бюллетеня" или "три бюллетня"?

Comment: Марина1502, будьте любезны ставить нормальные метки, чтобы потом не нужно было администрации это делать за Вас.

Answer (score 2):

Три бюллетеня.
Слово иноязычное, беглой гласной быть не может.